# how to make bootstrap v4 card group to share same header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap v4 [card-group](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#groups) for my project. 
And I want to add card-header to the card-group.

However, the `.card-header` class should be added to each of the card, I want to know if there is any solution to make the header shared by the cards in same row.

I attached the [codepen](http://codepen.io/bambooom/pen/Krqmyz) here. Eg, I want to have only one shared card-header `Topic` shown.

Thanks!

Comment: You can move `card-header` outside `card-group`.

Comment: @makshh oh! Thank you! But I found that there is small border radius difference which makes the header ugly.... I guess I may need some more css to adjust it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way is to create another class for that (it will not affect default Bootstrap CSS).

```
.card-header-custom {
  border-radius: .25rem .25rem 0 0;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.card-header-custom + .card-group > .card {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/VjWWwN)

Answer (score -1):

you need to move the `.card-header` into the root of the `.card-group`, then change the `display` to `table-caption`, only for when it's an immediate child of `.card-group`

[Demo](http://codepen.io/jcastillo/pen/RRgVBd)

```
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card-header">Topic</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Css

```
.card-group > .card-header{
  display: table-caption;
}
```